# java api for feeding tfrecords bytes to tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensor, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

Does any one know of high level api if exist in java for directly reading tfrecords and feeding to a tensorflow savedModel . Python api allows both example.proto (tfrecords) and tensors to be fed to tf model for inference. The only api i have seen in java is of creating raw tensors, is there a way similar to python sdk where i can directly feed tfrecords (example.proto_ to a saved model bundle in java as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across same scenario and I used [TFRecordIO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TFRecordIO.java) from Java Apache Beam to read records. For example,

`pipeline
  .apply(TFRecordIO.read().from(dataPath))
  .apply(ParDo.of(new ModelEvaluationFn()));`

Inside `ModelEvaluationFn` I do the scoring using `savedModel`. With Java Apache Beam, you can run locally, on GCP Dataflow, Spark, Flink, etc. But if you are using Spark directly, there's [spark-tensorflow-connector](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/tree/master/spark/spark-tensorflow-connector).

Another thing I came across is how to parse the tfrecords in Java because I need get the label value and group by using some column values to get breakdown scores. [org.tensorlfow/proto](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tensorflow/proto) package can help you do that. Here are examples: [example1](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/blob/master/hadoop/src/test/java/org/tensorflow/hadoop/io/TFRecordFileTest.java), [example2](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/blob/master/hadoop/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/hadoop/example/TFRecordFileMRExample.java). Essentially, it's `Example.parseFrom(byte[])`.